# the_category pulling div out of normal flow

Tags: php, html, wordpress

trying to use `<?php the_category( ' ' ); ?>` to put in my category from my wordpress post.

within the loop html

```
<a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>
   <section id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="..">

   <div> 

   <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?>
   <?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>

   </div>
</section>
</a>
```

Problem is that having the category php the section div's seems to get pulled out of the link (output has section outside link code.
Not having the category code it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue in your HTML: you have a `<a>` tag (inline element) with inside block type elements (like `<div>` and `<section>`).
Take a look at [this page](https://coursework.vschool.io/html-block-vs-inline/) in order to properly understand the difference between inline and block elements.

While using `the_category()`, you are going to displays a link to the category or categories a post belongs to, so you are also placing a `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag.

Because you want just display the categories' names, you can use the following code

```php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
    echo $category->name."<br>";
}
```

Review your formatting and everything will be work as expected.

Comment: Oh I get it, So I need to remove the a tag from the category, I just want the text

Comment: Updated answer, please check.